# Does having a cache manifest automatically cache all pages

Tags: html, caching, browser

Does the browser cache all pages listed in the cache manifest file upon loading the website or do you have to visit each page for it to be cached (and later accessed offline)?

I read MDN article on it and this article and this is what I took away

```
"any page the user navigates to that include a manifest will be implicitly added to the application cache"
```

Judging from the above it would seem that you must visit each page for it to cache. But I'm not sure if this was what they were trying to convey.

Does anyone know or have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

In short: all pages **listed in cache manifest** are cached upon loading the website.

---

To make things clear, let's analyse the sentence you mentioned. It says:

> any page the user navigates to that include a manifest will be implicitly added to the application cache

First, "page that includes manifest" is every page with manifest attribute on html tag:

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
    ...
</html>
```

Such a page will be "**implicitly** added to the application cache". The keyword is "implicitly". That means, this page will be added to application cache *even if it's not listed in manifest file*.

After you load a page, all pages/resources that are in manifest file referenced on this page are cached (without a need to visit them).

In addition, every page that is not listed in manifest, but includes manifest attribute is cached, but this happens **only if you visit that page**.

If my explanation is not clear, I can provide a short example.

Answer (score 0):

An application cache contains all resources specified in the cache manifest. That’s the whole point. The user does not need to “visit” them. (Normal visits would normally add them to the browser cache, but that’s a completely different issue.)  And an application cache is meant for *applications*, not web sites. An application cache is reloaded if and only if the cache manifest has changed. This is absurd for web sites, but it can make a lot of sense to applications.

The MDN page that you quote, with no citation, seems to say just that when a page that has an application cache manifest is visited, the page itself is added to the application cache even if it is not explicitly mentioned in the maniest.